# How to connect Turso DB with an Next13 app?

Tags: next.js, bun

Yo guys, I am building like a simple Next13 web app using Bun, and I want to connect to an db, sense Bun is highly support for SQLite,  I choose turso db because it is build on the top of a fork of SQLite, but if there is any better suggestion, please I will be glad to know.
So what I am trying is to connect my next app with my turso. the app is a simple. Blog with a simple search bar, that allows people to search for an article, if they did not fount it they can create an article about it, no signing are needed.
So if there is any resource or link, video or advice, I will really appreciate the help

*I did not try anything yet, just some researches but I don't hv no idea where to start*